# MongoEngine query list for objects having properties starting with prefixes specified in a list

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

I need to query Mongo database for elements that have a certain property beginning with any prefix in the list. Now I have a piece of code like this:

```
query = mymodel(terms__term__in=query_terms)
```

and this matches objects that have an item on a list "terms" that has StringField "term" explicitly occurring on a list "query_terms". What I want to achieve is having objects that have an item on a list "terms" that has StringField "term" beginning with any prefix that occurs on a list "query_terms". Is it possible to do it in one query and without storing every possible prefix of "term" in database?

**EDIT:**
The solution below works great but now I have to find objects with terms starting with every prefix on a list. I changed

```
query = reduce(lambda q1, q2: q1.__or__(q2), 
           map(lambda prefix: Q(terms__term__startswith=prefix)))
```

to

```
query = reduce(lambda q1, q2: q1.__and__(q2), 
           map(lambda prefix: Q(terms__term__startswith=prefix)))
```

but this does not work. I end up getting the following error:

```
InvalidQueryError: Duplicate query conditions: terms__term__startswith
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your querying a term for it's value, you can filter the values that begin with a perfix like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(terms__term__startswith='foo')
```

If you need to filter for multiple prefixes you'll have to create Q objects for that:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(terms__term__startswith='foo') | Q(terms__term__startswith='bar'))
```

If you need to create the query dynamically:

```
prefixes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
query = reduce(lambda q1, q2: q1.__or__(q2), 
               map(lambda prefix: Q(terms__term__startswith=prefix), prefixes))
MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression like `^(prefix1 | prefix2 etc)`:

```
prefixes = [....]
regex = '^(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, prefixes))
docs = your_collection.find({'term': {'$regex': regex}})
```

upd: didn't notice this question is about mongoengine. The above is for pure pymongo, don't know if ME allows this.