# Dynamically building an AND query in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Based on the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348874/mongoengine-query-list-for-objects-having-properties-starting-with-prefixes-spec), I was able to figure out how to dynamically build a complex query in mongo engine using map/reduce and lambda expressions.

However, as I've tried to switch my OR query to an AND query, I've run into trouble (ironically, the poster of the question above did, too, after his initial question was answered).

Here's the code I'm running:

```
titles = ['topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3']
query = reduce(lambda q1, q2: q1.__and__(q2), 
               map(lambda the_title: Q(slug__iexact=the_title), titles))
threats = Threat.objects.filter(query)
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
InvalidQueryError: Duplicate query conditions: slug__iexact
```

However, when I run the same code, but substituting `__and__` for `__or__`, the query works perfectly.

As always, I am not an expert, and am figuring things out as I go, so I'm probably missing something obvious.  Many thanks in advance for any ideas here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this this is special behaviour: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/ee725354db066ea11f25dd01387f8d3dcb721c6c/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py#L58.

Because this query will always False or just duplicate:

```
Q(slug__iexact='topic1') and Q(slug__iexact='topic2') <==> False
Q(slug__iexact='topic1') and Q(slug__iexact='topic1') <==> Q(slug__iexact='topic1')
```

But look like duplication ignored: `ops = set(query.keys())`, so this query doesn't have sense.

You must catch this exception and remove this query from filter because it doesn't have sense.